# How to truncate all strings in a list to a same length, in some pythonic way?

Tags: python

Let's say we have a list such as:

```
g = ["123456789123456789123456", 
     "1234567894678945678978998879879898798797", 
     "6546546564656565656565655656565655656"]
```

I need the first twelve chars of each element :

```
["123456789123", 
 "123456789467", 
 "654654656465"]
```

Okay, I can build a second list in a for loop, something like this:

```
g2 = []
for elem in g:
    g2.append(elem[:12])
```

but I'm pretty sure there are much better ways and can't figure them out for now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
g2 = [elem[:12] for elem in g]
```

If you prefer to edit `g` in-place, use the slice assignment syntax with a generator expression:

```
g[:] = (elem[:12] for elem in g)
```

Demo:

```
>>> g = ['abc', 'defg', 'lolololol']
>>> g[:] = (elem[:2] for elem in g)
>>> g
['ab', 'de', 'lo']
```

Comment: worthy to note that if the string is _shorter_ than 2 characters, it still works without throwing "IndexError". You'll just keep the original string.

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[elem[:12] for elem in g]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `map(...)` :

```
b = map(lambda x: x[:9],g)
```